# Deleting words which have uneven number of letters

Tags: c#

So, I need to delete all words which have odd number of letters in them. So far I have made that it deletes the last word in line who has odd number of letters. How I need to do that it would delete every word from line that has odd number of letters?
Text is in data file and I need to print the results to another file without deleted words.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Apdorojimas(CFd, CFr, CFv);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// reads data file and writes the text in result file without deleted words
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="duomenųFailas">data file</param>
    /// <param name="rezultatųFailas">results file</param>
    /// <param name="analizėsFailas">not needed</param>
    static void Apdorojimas(string duomenųFailas, string rezultatųFailas, string analizėsFailas)
    {
        string[] eilutė = File.ReadAllLines(duomenųFailas, Encoding.GetEncoding(1257));
        using (var fr = File.CreateText(rezultatųFailas))
        {
            foreach (string line in eilutė)
            {
                    if (line.Length > 0)
                    {

                        string nauja = line;

                        fr.WriteLine(Ištrinti(nauja));
                    }
                    else
                        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (line.Length == 0)
                            {
                                line.Remove(i);
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// deletes the word with odd number of letters
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eilutė">Line</param>
    /// <returns>line with deleted word</returns>
    static string Ištrinti(string eilutė)
    {
        char[] skyrikliai = { ' ' };

        string[] parts = eilutė.Split(skyrikliai, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string eil = eilutė;
        foreach (string žodis in parts)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < eilutė.Length - 1; i++)
                if (žodis.Length % 2 != 0)
                {
                    eil = eilutė.Remove(eilutė.IndexOf(žodis), žodis.Length);

                }

        }
        return eil;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is your actual question..?

Comment: How do you count the length? Do apostrophes count as a letter (as in: "*don't* delete me!")? Do numbers count as letters? You are splitting on the space character, which means the ending punctuation in sentences will be included with the last word in the sentence. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
static String Ištrinti(string eilutė)
{
    // build a list from the split
    List<String> parts = new List<String>(eilutė.Split({' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    // iterate the list starting from the bottom
    for (Int32 i = parts.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        // if the length of the current string is odd remove it
        if ((parts[i].Length % 2) != 0)
            parts.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    // join the remaining list elements into a single string
    return String.Join(" ", parts);
}
```

Using `LINQ`:

```
static String Ištrinti(string eilutė)
{
    // build a list from the split
    List<String> parts = new List<String>(eilutė.Split({' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    // create another list selecting only the strings with an even length
    List<String> partsEven = parts.Where(s => (s.Length % 2) == 0).ToList();

    // join the new list elements into a single string
    return String.Join(" ", partsEven);
}
```

Comment: Or your linq version could be one line: `return string.Join(" ", eilutė.Split().Where(s => s.Length > 0 && s.Length % 2 == 0));`

Comment: Maybe there is another way without using List<string> , Int32 because we can't use in our programs codes that we haven't learned?

Comment: Using RemoveEmptyEntries makes unnecessary to check for length > 0. Anyway I fixed my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Vilius, Int32 is just an alias of int... how can this be you aren't allowed to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using `List`. I'll assume that there are multiple words per line, separated by spaces.

The basic idea is that you do this for every line:

1. Start at the beginning of the line.
2. Move forward through the characters until you find the start of a word.
3. Save that position.
4. Move another index forward until you find the first space after the word, or the end of the line.
5. You compute the word length by `(last-char-pos - first-char-pos)`
6. If the number is even, write the word to the output file.
7. Reset start to the current end position, and go back to step 2.

C# code:

```
using (var output_file = File.CreateText("outputFile.txt"))
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("inputFile.txt"))
    {
        int start = 0;
        while (start < line.Length)
        {
            // look for start of word
            while (start < line.Length && line[start] == ' ')
            {
                ++start;
            }

            if (start >= line.Length)
            {
                // no more words on line
                break;
            }

            // now look for end of word
            int end = start+1;
            while (end < line.Length && line[end] != ' ')
            {
                ++end;
            }

            int length = end - start;
            if ((length % 2) == 0)
            {
                output_file.WriteLine(line.Substring(start, length));
            }

            // reposition start for next word
            start = end;
        }
    }
}
```

That's the basic idea. I haven't tested the code, so you probably want to do that.